# Dynamically adding variables to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript question. What the best way of writing the following Javascript code dynamically. Keep in mind that I have to write the code using php echo tags. So the browser can translate it a JavaScript. Thanks

```
  var one = {
    info: { name: "John" }
   };

  var two = {
    info: { name: "Henry" }
  };

  var simple_config = [ one,two ];
```

//SOLUTION

```
<script>
var page = <?php  echo json_encode($tree_data->result_array()); ?> 
<?php 
 var $page_data =  echo json_encode($tree_data->result_array()); // assoc array from database

foreach ($page as $row){

 echo 'var $row['student_number'] = {
           text: { name: "Name" }
            };';

echo " var class = [];";

echo "class.push($row['student']);";


}?>
</script>

<script>
     new ClassRegistry(simple_chart_config); //pre-defined custom function
</script>
```

Comment: Print javascript based values with PHP.

Comment: Should henry be in `var two`?

Comment: Use `json_encode()` in PHP to convert a PHP array into a Javascript literal. Don't bother with the variables.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` would do the trick. However if you still want to do it your way, you can use code below as starting point.

Something like that would do it.

```
$myArr = ['name' => 'Test'];
print "var one = {"; //Variable declaration
foreach ($myArr as $k => $v) {
    print $k . ': "' . $v . '",'; //All the keys and values
}
print "};"  //Close brackets
```

This would print:

```
var one = {name: "Test",};
```

Comment: I dont think I explained  what I was trying to accomplished correctly....II have posted a solution my original post.